# Convert fixed gear to coaster bike

Tags: wheels, coaster, hub, conversion

I want to convert my fixed gear 700c bike (raleigh rush hour) to coaster break bike. Can anyone recomend the best way to do this. Can anyone recomend a good coaster rear hub or coaster rear wheel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done two ways:

1. **Easy way:** Purchase a new 700c wheel with coaster brake hub from your Local Bike Shop or the internet. It may be hard to find this as it is not a particularly popular option, but it's not uncommon to find one at a well-appointed bike shop.
2. **Hard way**: Purchase a new coaster brake hub, and rebuild your existing rear wheel (or have it rebuilt--wheel building is a complex process) with the new hub. One advantage to rebuilding your existing wheel is that it will be easier to find a new or used, unbuilt coaster-brake hub. Additionally, you'll be sure to have matching front & rear rims.

Other than that, there are no other steps or considerations you'll need to take.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great set of coaster wheels online at espresso wheels dot com. They sell ready made deep V coaster wheels in four colours: white, matt black, polished silver and turquoise for £139. They also do custom wheel builds, sell the rims and hubs separately and ship anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to make certain the reaction arm is properly and securely fixed to the frame. During mad skidzzzz there will be serious force put on it, so don't take the matter likely. If it comes loose while stopping, not only might it make stopping a challenge, it can destroy the hub bearings.

Comment: And it's wise to consider whether the frame is built to withstand the forces involved.  Generally the arm is fixed to the chainstay, but a violent stop could rip loose a lightly-fastened chainstay.  Not as big a problem as putting disks on a front fork not designed for disks, but the same basic concern.